# understanding SED commands

Tags: bash, google-maps, shell, google-maps-api-3, sed

I need to understand a shell code which uses the following command to fetch directions from a source to destination using GOOGLE MAPS API:

```
wget --no-parent -O - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$begin\&destination=$finish\&sensor=false > new.txt
```

Next we fetch the following line of the output:

```
**"html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enorthwest\u003c/b\u003e"**
```

```
grep -n html_instructions  new.txt > new1.txt
```

Can somebody please tell me the meaning of using:

```
sed -e 's/\\u003cb//g'
```

etc in the following command:

```
sed -e 's/\\u003cb//g' -e 's/\\u003e//g' -e 's/\\u003c\/b//g' -e 's/\\u003c//g' -e 's/div.*div//g' -e 's/.*://g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ "//g' new1.txt > new2.txt
```

Which outputs `Head northwest` only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\\u003cb//g' -e 's/\\u003e//g' -e 's/\\u003c\/b//g' -e 's/\\u003c//g' -e 's/div.*div//g' -e 's/.*://g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ "//g' new1.txt > new2.txt
```

The string after each `-e` is a `sed` command.  The sed command `s/\\u003cb//g` searches for all occurrences of the unicode character 003CB (which is [a greek small letter upsilon with dialytika](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/parsers/rst/include/isogrk2.txt)) and replaces it with nothing.  In other words, it remove the character from the string.

Thus, that `sed` command removes every occurrence of unicode characters 003cb, u003e, and u003c from the lines and new1.txt and sends the output to new2.txt.

Additionally, `s/div.*div//g` causes any string that begins and ends with "div" to be removed.  The command `s/.*://g` removes any text from the beginning of the line to the last colon in the line.  `s/"//g` removes the every occurence of the double-quote character.  `s/ "//g` removes every occurrence of space followed by double-quote.

In general, the `sed` command `s/new/old/` searches for the first occurrence of new and replaces it with old.  With a `g` appended at the end, as in `s/new/old/g`, it makes the substitution globally: looks for every occurrence of new and replaces it with old.  Adding a lot of power to these commands, `new` may be a regular expression.  Consider `s/.*:`//g`.  The dot character has the special meaning of "any character at all".  The star character means zero or more of the preceding character.  Thus the regular expression`.*:` means zero or more of any characters followed by a colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all in one go with `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '/html_instructions/ {gsub(/(\\u003(c|cb|e)|\/b)/,x);print $4}'
Head northwest
```

So whole line should be:

```
wget --no-parent -O - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$begin\&destination=$finish\&sensor=false | awk -F\" '/html_instructions/ {gsub(/(\\u003(c|cb|e)|\/b)/,x);print $4}'
Head northwest
```

to get it into a variable

```
d=$(wget --no-parent -O - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$begin\&destination=$finish\&sensor=false | awk -F\" '/html_instructions/ {gsub(/(\\u003(c|cb|e)|\/b)/,x);print $4}')
echo $d
Head northwest
```